# Referencing an INTERNAL table via SQL in a C# project

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

This just got dumped on me, so the first answer is "No, I can't change it."

There's a table in SQL Server with a schema of INTERNAL\N55XX1.  I'm trying to write some C# code-behind so I can pull the contents out and put them in a dropdown list.  I've never done this before with anything that wasn't "dbo.", and it's not working.  What I've got is:

```
    private void LoadFilterNames()
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str))
        {

            try
            {
                //    string cboActive = Convert.ToString(cboFilterOption.SelectedValue);
                string strSQL = "SELECT Sample_Title FROM tbl_Sample_Title ORDER BY Sample_Title;";

                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(strSQL, con);
                DataSet SmpTitle = new DataSet();
                adapter.Fill(SmpTitle);

                cboSmpTitle.DataSource = SmpTitle;
                cboSmpTitle.DataTextField = "Sample_Title";
                cboSmpTitle.DataValueField = "Sample_Title";
                cboSmpTitle.DataBind();


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Handle the error
                Console.WriteLine("Making Call to " + ex + "");

            }
            con.Close();

        }

        // Insert a blank row into the DropDownLists so there is no default name
        //  DropDownList_Reporting_RunForDaily.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("", ""));
        // cboFilterOption.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("", ""));

    }
```

I've also tried writing the SQL string as:

```
"SELECT Sample_Title FROM INTERNAL\N55XX1.tbl_Sample_Title ORDER BY Sample_Title;"
```

but the N after the backslash becomes underlined and when you hover the mouse over it there's a message that says, "Unrecognized escape sequence".

Comment: I get the Same error.

Comment: Also are you sure that `INTERNAL\N55XX1` is actually the schema? It definitely isn't the `N55XX1` named instance running on the `INTERNAL` server?

Comment: Slightly off topic.  But you have no layers at all.  A SqlConnection should not show up in the same code as a comboBox.....even if you're writing code for your kids soccer team.  IMHO.  Some basic layering is not too hard.

Comment: @granadaCoder - Yeah, that's all stuff I need to go back and fix.  This whole project is FUBAR from the start, I'm just trying to patch it for now...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `FROM [INTERNAL\N55XX1].tbl_Sample_Title` in the query as this is not a standard TSQL identifier and must be delimited.

Also prefix the C# string literal with `@` to create a [verbatim string literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx) and avoid the "Unrecognized escape sequence" issue.

```
string strSQL = 
 @"SELECT Sample_Title FROM [INTERNAL\N55XX1].tbl_Sample_Title ORDER BY Sample_Title;";
```

Comment: You just saved my life.  Or at least my sanity.